# How to set file permission on resource files in the Eclipse buildpath?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a maven project (on linux), with the following resource folder (containing one file):

```
* src/main/resources 
-rw-r--r-- 1 my-user 18737 1740 Oct 25 10:24 log4j.properties
```

When Eclipse compiles my project, it copies resource files to the output (bin) folder:

```
* ${project}/target/classes 
-rw------- 1 my-user 18737 1740 Oct 25 10:24 log4j.properties
```

but it changes the file permission. Is there any way to control this? I would like to preserve the original file permissions.

I have tried with setting "`umask 002`", before starting Eclipse, with no luck. Could not find a solution via google.

Anyone here who knows how to do it?